# What's the need of $\delta$ in the definition of Lyapunov stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I’m having trouble understanding Lyapunov stability, which is

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0: \|\bar x(0)\| < \delta\implies \forall t \ge 0, \|\bar x(t)\| < \epsilon$

Why is the need for the $\delta$? Couldn’t we just say that both our equilibrium point and the state trajectory must remain in the $\epsilon$-ball?

That is, why shouldn't the definition be

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \|\bar x(0)\| < \epsilon \implies \forall t \ge 0, \|\bar x(t)\| < \epsilon$

[image]

Comment: That's the definition. If you want $\epsilon = \delta$, that's fine but it is not Lypunov stability.

Comment: How would your condition then look? If we just take away everything with $\delta$ in this definition, we get $\forall \varepsilon \forall t \ge 0, \| x(t) \| < \varepsilon$, which is only fulfilled for $x \equiv 0$.

Comment: Stability means that if you move away from $x(0)$ a little bit, then $x(t)$ also only moves away a little bit from $x(0)$.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon>0 :\; \|\bar x(0)\|<\epsilon\,\Rightarrow\,\forall t\ge 0\;\|\bar x(t)\|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Eigenbrödler There are little chances that if at zero the solution is close to $\epsilon$, it will remain smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Without knowing a thing about Lyapunov stability, its definition looks a lot like the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity between metric spaces, so this should probably be the explanation: the mapping from the initial condition to some later time should be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the definition of Lyapunov stability, there are cases that $\|x(0)\| < \epsilon$ does not imply that $\|x(t)\| <\epsilon$. For example, consider the linear system

\begin{align}
x' &= -2y, \\ y' &= x.
\end{align}

Since $(x^2 + 2y^2)' = 2xx' + 4yy'= 0$, the solutions lies inside the ellipse

$$ x^2 + 2y^2 = c.$$

In particular, given any $\epsilon >0$, the solution with $\|x(0)\|<\epsilon$ might leave the ball with radius $\epsilon$. This system is Lyapunov stable, but not stable in the definition you proposed.

FYI: the stability that you proposed is equivalent to $x\cdot f(x) \le 0$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$.